# My lack of understanding LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Ok I have several tables linked together.

```
Departments (k = departmentID)
Functions (k = functionID, fk = departmentID)
Processes (k = processID, fk = functionID)
Procedures (k = procedureID, fk = processID)
```

So they all have their relationships setup when trying to come up with some linq I run into some oddities.

The below code will return me

```
Departments.Select(s => s.Functions)
```

[image]

But when trying to expand that query further it will not let me.  I'd like to be able to join all of the above tables and pull information out of them as I need it.

```
Departments.Select(s => s.Functions.Process.Procedure) // Errors out
```

Further more I can do the following:

```
Functions.Select(s => s.Processes)
```

It seems it will do it for two tables but no more than 2?  Am I missing something?

Comment: This is LINQ to what? EF?

Comment: Currently im running the lambda in Linq Pad and pulling results directly from Sql Server. @AndrewWhitaker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the thing.  The `Departments` to `Functions` relationship is one to many.  So when you just write,

```
 Departments
```

you have a collection of `Department` objects.  Since each `Department` object has its own collection of `Function` objects, doing:

```
 Departments.Select(departmentObject => departmentObject.Functions)
```

gives you a collection of collections of `Function` objects.

If you want to aggregate all these together, you have to use a different method, specifically

```
 Departments.SelectMany(departmentObject => departmentObject.Functions)
```

which says "get the collection of collections of `Function` objects and make them into one big collection of `Function` objects"

What you are trying to do is:

```
Departments.Select(departmentObject => departmentObject .Functions.Process.Procedure)
```

But, this can't possibly work, because you are asking a collection of `Function` objects for its `Process` property.  But, a collection of `Function` objects doesn't have a `Process` property.  A `Function` object, itself, has a `Process` property.  So, what you are really trying to do is:

```
 Departments
     .SelectMany(departmentObject => departmentObject.Functions)
     .Select(functionObject => functionObject.Process.Procedure)
```

which basically translates to "get the collection of collections of `Function` objects and make them into one big collection of `Function` objects.  Then, get the `Procedure` property of the `Process` property of each `Function` object".

So, what you should be expecting here is just a collection of the procedures that are performed by the processes of any function associated with any of the departments.

Note, that if there is any overlap in the Functions of Departments, in the Processes of Functions, or in the Procedures of Processes, then you may get some duplicate Procedures in your end result.  If this isn't what you want, then you can use the `Distinct()` method to remove duplicates, and you should do so at any point where there is overlap, but there should not be duplication.  You can get the same result by simply adding `Distinct()` to the end of the query, but you will have better performance if you kill the duplicates along the way.  So, in reality, your query will probably look like something in between the following and previous query, depending on how much overlap there is and how much duplication you want:

```
 Departments
     .SelectMany(departmentObject => departmentObject.Functions)
     .Distinct()
     .Select(functionObject => functionObject.Process)
     .Distinct()
     .Select(processObject => processObject.Procedure)
     .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer.  It helped me understand linq better.  Is there a reason not to use .SelectMany for all three?  Or does it depend exactly what I am trying to accomplish?  The database is basically A department can have many functions, a function can have many processes, a process can have many procedures.

Comment: actually I think I understand ti a bit better now.  I had to turn the second .Select unto a SelectMany to return a collection of the procedures.

Comment: And there should be 0 duplication in this database if I handle all the code correctly. :)

Comment: @JamesWilson, `SelectMany` is used for when you want to get a collection for each element and then merge the collections into one big collection.  `Select` is used for when you just want to select a single object for each element.  I did the best I could to guess what your model looked like given the code provided.

Comment: And it was much appreciated.  I did not mean my comment to be a downgrade or ridicule in anyway.  I am very new to linq, so this learning experience was much appreciated.