# Troublesome LINQ query/join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Ok I'm not even sure where to begin on this.  I have four main tables.

`IPACS_Departments` (one to many) -> `IPACS_Functions` (one to many) -> `IPACS_Processes` (one to many) -> `IPACS_Procedures`

I have an `IPACS_Documents` table with a primary key for `docID`.

I have 4 look up tables.

`IPACS_DepartmentDocs` -> `IPACS_FunctionDocs`  -> `IPACS_ProcesseDocs` -> `IPACS_ProcedureDocs`

Each of those tables have a `FK` to the `IPACS_Document` table `docID`
They also have a `FK` to my first four tables mentioned on `departmentID`, `functionID`, `processID`, `procedureID`.

I need to somehow wire these together though a LINQ statement.

For my department view page.  I need to show every single document that is in the current department.

For example we have a computer department.  That has 2 functions within that department, that has 13 processes within those functions and 41 procedures within those processes.

So on my department view page I need to show all of the documents for that department and it's functions and it's processes and it's procedures.

On my department view page I have access to the `departmentID`.

Where I am 100% confused is how do I get all of the associated documents using these 9 different tables?

I hope that made sense because my brain is friend trying to think through this.

Comment: LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework or something else?

Comment: @TimB LINQ to Entity sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have your model down right, but I think it follows this pattern (assuming Entity Framework, with the descendant entities having mapping properties to allow the heirarchy to be walked):

```
public class Department
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Function> Functions { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<DepartmentDocument> DepartmentDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentDocument
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Department")]
  public int DeptId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Document")]
  public int DocId { get; set; }

  public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

  public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual DepartmentDocument DepartmentDocument { get; set; }

  public virtual FunctionDocument FunctionDocument { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming a model like this, then you can write the following - I've only included traversing two levels, but the extras just need some extra lines with `SelectMany()` for the child elements:

```
public List<Document> GetDocumentsForDepartment(List<Department> departments)
{
  var docs = new List<Document>();

  foreach (var department in departments)
  {
    foreach (var ddoc in department.DepartmentDocuments)
    {
      docs.Add(ddoc.Document);
    }

    foreach (var fx in department.Functions)
    {
      foreach (var fdoc in fx.FunctionDocuments)
      {
        docs.Add(fdoc.Document);
      }
    }  
  }

  return docs;
}
```

Which simplifies to:

```
public List<Document> GetDocumentsForDepartment2(List<Department> departments)
{
  var docs = new List<Document>();

  foreach (var department in departments)
  {
    docs.AddRange(department.DepartmentDocuments.Select(ddoc => ddoc.Document));
    docs.AddRange(department.Functions.SelectMany(fx => fx.FunctionDocuments, (fx, fdoc) => fdoc.Document));
  }

  return docs;
}
```

This might be OK, the scheme uses more than one DB call (if you are using EF and not Linq to Objects). If that sucks, then maybe you need to put a view in the DB.

I couldn't think how to write this as a single linq query, so maybe this is just a starting point for further work.

This is a pretty simple follow-up to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367539/my-lack-of-understanding-linq?rq=1) though. When you're looking to aggregate child data, you need `SelectMany()`.

Comment: Thank you very much I will take this and work with it.  You were correct with the models, the only thing I don't have is the Data Annotations for "Foreign Key".  Now to start plugging away and tackle this thing.